# Entity Framework Core migrations failing with "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading'"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've been making some changes to the following open source project: https://github.com/SevenSpikes/api-plugin-for-nopcommerce

I am trying to update `IdentityServer4` library referenced in the above project from 2.0.3 to 2.4.0. As part of this process I require the migrations scripts from the previous version to the current. I also wanted to get some experience generating migrations scripts as I have never done it before.

I have tried executing the following command

```
> dotnet ef migrations add
> InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c
> PersistedGrantDbContext -o /Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb --project "C:\localpath\Nop.Plugin.Api.csproj"
```

based on the [following documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/7_entity_framework.html)

and when I do so I receive the following error

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at System.Console.get_IsOutputRedirected()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I have attempted to update to the latest version of the [Core 2.2 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) and it doesn't seem to have helped.

Bit stuck and would appreciate some help!

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @AntonToshik Yeah sorry, Windows and Visual Studio 2017. Tried both in package manager console and command prompt

Comment: I am thinking it's an issue inside the .csproj file, it might have added a faulty reference. Does your project build? (Delete bin/obj folders)

Comment: I ran into this problem. this is not the right answer for your problem, but for me i specified a migration assembly in startup then moved the code to another project
options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("connStr")//,
                    //x => x.MigrationsAssembly("the name in your error")
                    ));

Comment: Got the same problem here and when I run the Add-Migration in Package Manager Console in VS2019 I'll get 'The specified deps.json does not exist'